# why list becomes none object when we append some element and assign to same list object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

why list becomes none object when we append some element and assign to same list object?

Example:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3]
```

so for

```
>>> x=x.append(4)
```

x will give `None` object

Comment: `x.append()` directly appends the element to the list and returns `None`. So, you don't need to save that in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer to this will be the following :

```
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> x.append(4)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It should be noted that the append() function itself modifies the object and hence further assigning is not needed.

You are getting `None` because after executing the `append()`, the function returns `None` as it's value and you have assigned it to the variable `x` itself.

I hope it clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Because return type of append() is **None**

> Return Value from append()
>
> **> As mentioned, the append() method only modifies the original list. It
>   doesn't return any value.**